# 汗をかくvs 発汗する - is there a difference?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, words, wago-and-kango

Is there any difference between 汗をかく and 発汗する? Are there any subtle nuances between the two or is one more common than the other? I've checked WWWJDIC and I can't find any way to distinguish between the two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Sino-Japanese 発汗{はっかん}する 'perspire' sounds more like a formal, technical term, like you might find in a medical context.  It isn't particularly common in normal speech.  Imagine saying this in English:

> Man, I just ran five miles!  I **perspired** so much!

Sounds pretty silly, right?  The first sentence sounds like casual English, but then I use the Latinate *perspire* in my next sentence, and it seems really out of place.  It sounds too formal or technical for casual speech, like something out of a medical textbook.

Something like this would be more natural:

> Man, I just ran five miles!  I really worked up a **sweat**!

Similarly, 発汗{はっかん} 'perspiration' just isn't the basic term for 'sweat' in Japanese.  If you just want to talk about sweat in normal speech, the native Japanese 汗 'sweat' is much more common, and 汗をかく is a simple and common phrase meaning 'to sweat'.