# Can we use ~た form to make a verb an adverb?

Tags: interpretation, past

I've got this phrase:

> コンタクトすると目が乾いた感じになって、目が赤くなります。

Which means:

> When I use contacts, my eyes feel dry and become red.

Pretty easy, but there's a little thing with the usage of the ~た form which I don't understand.
When they say 目が乾いた感じになって, I'd rather have used 目が乾性{かんせい}な感じになって, to express the dry feeling. Would this also be correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This 乾いた is perfectly fine and natural. Here, 乾いた is a relative clause that modifies 感じ, so this 乾いた is functionally more like an adjective than an adverb.

- [What are the general principles of using verbs to modify nouns (e.g. 焦げるトースト/焦げたトースト)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11975/5010)
- ["太ってる猫" vs "太った猫"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3361/5010)

In your case, 感じ ("feeling") is not a tangible object, but the same principle applies. 乾いた感じ refers to a feeling that something has dried.

On the other hand, 乾性 sounds awfully strange in a context like this. For one thing, 乾性 is a highly stiff technical term (See:   [汗をかくvs 発汗する - is there a difference?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33685/5010)). For another, 乾性 usually refers to a type of a product, etc., not a state of something. If you want to use a kango, you can say 目が乾燥した感じになって (乾燥 is not so stiff, and usually is safe in casual conversations).